# TFS 2012 - Specified Email Alerting

Tags: tfs

Good Day All,

I was wondering if there was a way to do email trigger alerting to a specified email address when the state of an implementation task changes?  First, I'd like to specify what email address the alerting goes to(this would be the requestor of the project and not someone on the team), and then trigger it when the state of the task is changed from Active to Closed(Completed). Attached is a preview of the tasks I'm speaking of:

[image]

I'm using VS 2012 with TFS 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. You can refer to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms181334.aspx) for more info.